# Codeigniter how to use get_where() to search in a column that contains part of a string?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Apologies if the title is confusing. Currently I have this as part of a get_where function:

```
$query = $this->db->select('*');
$query = $this->db->get_where('Accounts', array('active' => 1));
return $this->result_array($query);
```

How can I add to the `get_where()` statement to also look in a specific column that contains a string value I tell it to look for? For example, I want it to also look in the column AccountKey and return all rows that contain the string '120-' in that column, in addition to `active = 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like for this, Your query would become something as follows:

```
$query = $this->db
            ->select('*')
            ->from('Accounts')
            ->where('active', 1)
            ->like('AccountKey', '120-', 'after')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you! I believe this is what I'm looking for.